# Dynamically changing/choosing the type of a class member variable

Tags: c++, polymorphism, containers

So I'm really rusty with my C++, and I'm trying to implement a compact mapping container as an exercise. I'm trying to figure out the best way to let my class choose the best/smallest type for a dynamically allocated array. Further this type may change during the lifetime of the object.

The idea is that you break up a hash table into the table and the data:

`table: [-1, -1, 2, -1, 1, 0]`

`data: [ [h0, key0, value0], [h1, key1, value1], [h2, key2, value2] ]`

When preforming lookups, you hash the key % table size, and get the corresponding index in the data array. By keeping the actual hash table sparse and as small and light as possible, you can get some good caching speed etc. Also, the elements can be iterated over in order.

To keep the table small, I want it to use the smallest possible datatype to hold the indexes (with headroom to minimize collisions):

- char up to 127 items
- short up to 2**15
- int up to 2**31
- longs afterward

As more entries are added, the table array will need to resize and eventually change type. I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this in my container.

Since I'm going to have to be using the table array type in my definitions, I'm going to have to use some kind of polymorphism. I don't think a template will work, since type can change and won't be known at runtime.

I've read a little about unions and variants, but from what I understand of them, I don't think they'll work.

I know a bit of C, but I know that using void pointers is frowned upon in C++.

The best I've come up with is some kind of base class to tell my container that the `table` arrays all support the same interface. But it seems like I'd be duplicating a lot of code and inserting some virtual function lookups for something I want to keep simple and fast as possible.

```cpp
template <typename K, typename V>
struct Entry {
    int hash;
    V value;
    K key;
};

class Table {
    public:
        virtual int operator[](int) =0;
}

class CharTable: public Table {
    public:
        CharTable(int s) :t{new char[s]}{}
        int operator[](int i) { return t[i]; }
        ~CharTable() {delete t[];}
    private:
        char* t;
}

// short table etc...

template <typename K, typename V>
class CompactMapping {
    public:
        CompactMapping();
        V& operator[](const K&);
        unsigned int size() const {return sz;}
        void resize(unsigned int);
    private:
        vector<Entry<K,V>> entries;
        unsigned int sz;
        Table* table;
        int allocated;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
V& CompactMapping<K, V>::operator[](const K& key){
    //simplified
    int index = table[hash(key) % allocated];
    if (entries[index].key == key){
        return entries[index].value;
    }
}

template <typename K, typename V>
void CompactMapping<K, V>::resize(unsigned int s){
    if (s <= 2**7)
        CharTable* t = new CharTable(s);
    if (s <= 2**15)
        ShortTable* t = new ShortTable(s);
    //... maybe a switch statement instead

    for (int i=0; i!=sz; ++i)
        t[entries[i].hash %s] = i;
    delete *table;
    table = t;
    allocated = s;    
}
```

Full disclosure I haven't actually tested this, so the implementation might be off. I just want to know before I go down this road if my thinking is okay or if there's a better solution.

I'd also appreciate any other advice you guys could give me.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. The hash table is an array of data. The data type does not depend on how many elements are in the array. The *index* type might, but you don't have any arrays of indices.

Comment: @n.m. The datatype does matter, because I want to change the datatype as the table get's larger. If I were going to hold 256 indexes using longs,  it would take 2048 bytes. If I were to store those same 256 indexes as char it would take only 256 bytes.

Comment: What you might save with reduced hash table sizes this might be eaten up by the virtual function call. Virtual functions always need an extra "trampoline jump" not to mention that they prevent inlining. To beat the `std` containers is probably not so easy... ;-)

Comment: @scheff I figured that was the case. I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to do it rather than a helper function that dispatches to different (but almost entirely identical) implementations of the container class.

Comment: I'm afraid the only way out would be polymorphy at compile time. -> The size of hash table and appropriate access functions is chosen by template arguments (i.e. at compile time).

Comment: @Scheff Yeah, I'm thinking a facade that dispatches to a template with three types: `CompactMapping<Key, Value, TableType>`.

Comment: OK I think I'm missing something. "The idea is that you break up a hash table into the table and the data". It isn't at all clear what you gain by this. It looks like you have introduced double indirection here. Why do you think it will be any faster than single indirection you normally have with a hash table?

Comment: @n.m. It's the difference between seperate chaining and open addressing hash tables. O-addressing is faster because of cache performance, you don't have to chase pointers randomly around memory and it's slightly smaller because you don't need the list pointers. The weakness is that if your stored object is large there will be large random gaps of empty but allocated space. by separating the hashing to it's own table, the data can be store densely packed and contiguously in order, while the index table can be kept small. Resizing/hashing is fast and an 8 item table fits in a single cache line.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it. Your key doesn't fit in the index table. You need to go to the object table every time and it doesn't fit in the cache. I don't think open addres hash tables work as you describe. The idea of open address hash table is that if you have a collision, you go to tge next entry rather than chase pointers, and the next entry is close to the one you already have so it's cache friendly. You don't store indices there, you store *keys*.

Comment: @n.m. The actual implementation uses perturbation for collisions. On collisions you will have to make bounces between the table and the data. But, say I have 6  64 byte objects in 8 allocated slots. If I need to reduce collisions on pure open addressing, I have to zero 16*64=1024 bytes of space and then copy 384 bytes of data into their new slots. With compact mapping, you need to zero only 16 bytes, and place 6 bytes into them. Copying of data items only happens when your data array fills. This container isn't my design, it's in use in the wild and real world lookup performance is excellent.

Comment: Ok I think I get the idea of the design, seems clever but can you point at an actual implementation in the wild?

Comment: @n.m. I know java had something similar a while back. I think topaz uses the same thing. But I know that zend php has an implementation: https://nikic.github.io/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html  and there's a c implementation in python: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c  Every object in python is a hashtable so they have some key-sharing and other optimizations as well. Here's an explanation of the compact design when it was first proposed: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CharTable: public Table
```

You probably want this instead:

```
template <class Index> class TypedTable : publlic Table { ... };
using CharTable = TypedTable<unsigned char>; // etc
```

This eliminates code duplication.

Now using a virtual call won't make the implementation win any speed competition, but you should profile first. If there's a significant bottleneck at the virtual call, try making your own dispatch mechanism using e.g. a `switch` statement and see if it helps. Using a `void` pointer is relatively benign as it is confined to a tightly controlled piece of code. Or you can use `std::variant` or your own implementation of a tagged union.

Comment: Thanks! Templating will eliminate a lot of the boilerplate. I'll take another look at variants. I was under the impression you couldn't allocate them on the heap, so I didn't read too closely, though if I choose my small sizes I guess I may not have to.